# Develop Android application for minimum Version 2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have developed android application keeping minimum api level 8 and maximum 17. Used Api 14 compilation unit.When I run it on android phone the application crashes.I wan to create application for Android 2.0 -3.0 version i.e the application should be compatible on 2.0 version also. Kindly suggest how can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you post app crashed logcat

Comment: Android 2.1 and lower cover less than the 0.1% of the current market. I suggest you to support 2.2+ (Froyo currently covers the 0.7% of the world market)

Comment: Anything below API level 10 (2.3.3) is no longer relevant.

Comment: Not for me. 0.7% of the world market (API Level 8, 2.2) is **very relevant**, for me.

Comment: I don't understand why you have set the minimum API to 8 which is Android 2.2, if you want it to run on Android 2.0 the minimum SDK should be set to API 5.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't allow me to create new project with minimum version 2.0 . Images are on links [link](http://i58.tinypic.com/35n0i8l.png).  [link](http://i60.tinypic.com/t56ji8.png) <img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/35n0i8l.png">

Answer (score 0):

Because you compile against level 14 API, you might use methods or classes that are not available on API level 8, which will cause runtime errors on level 8 devices.

I suggest you compile your app against the API Level 8 SDK.

Android Lint tool in Eclipse can also find usages of methods that are not available on your app's minimum API level, but I'm not sure how much reliable its results are (It might not find all of the unavailable classes/methods).

Comment: Whenever I start developing application in android it shows error that the theme targets api is.... I am unable to create any project with 2.0 version i.e api level 5